# Which preposition to use with stehen?

Tags: preposition

To translate this fragment of dialog, which is taken verbatim from I Asimov's "I, Robot":

> “Now where are we?” “Exactly at the explanation."

which preposition is correct, and why?

> »An welchen Punkt sind wir jetzt gekommen?« »Wir stehen genau **bei** der Erläuterung.

> »An welchen Punkt sind wir jetzt gekommen?« »Wir stehen genau **an** der Erläuterung.

Or something else?

Comment: I feel the choice of words is unidiomatic in both languages and you would probably word it completely differently. Can you give more context?

Comment: @Raketenolli -Yes, on the English side you "arrive at" a conclusion, not "to". Or you can "reach" a conclusion, or simply "conclude" something. These all sound rather formal in spoken English, maybe "So, have we figured anything out yet?" Also, would "*Ergebnis*" be a better match for this sense of "conclusion"? On the second sentence, you generally "explain" something, not "arrive at" and explanation. The use of "arrive" here is a metaphor that's turned into a figure of speech, but an English speaker would struggle to connect it back to the metaphor and use it with another word.

Comment: You've just changed the English sentence, but you have not adjusted the translation accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> Now where are we? – Exactly at the explanation.

For the sake of idiomacy, I would translate this according to the meaning rather than literally, for example:

> Wo stehen wir jetzt? – Genau *am Punkt* der Erläuterung.

Answer (score 0):

You may translate that literally. The logic is exactly the same in German.

> Wo sind wir jetzt? — Genau bei der Erläuterung.

Comment: But why is it bei der Erläuterung and not an der Erläuterung?

Comment: Because the phrase ist *bei etwas sein* if you mean steps to take. The phrase *an etwas sein* does not exist.The question suggested the phrase to use in the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Janka, you wrote "*an etwas sein* does not exist." This is wrong. Counter example: "Wir *sind an der Haltestelle*.“

Comment: That's not a verb phrase but that expression *an der Haltestelle* is a locational adverbial. The main problem with the original phrasing is that it's *not* about a location but instead a fixed phrase that treats a step from a list like a location. But that makes it a phrasal verb: you aren't free in your choice of preposition then.

Comment: According to this post, German does not have phrasal verbs. So I have re-opened my question, as all answers given do not explain the choice of preposition. https://bit.ly/3UvZIQC

Comment: If German doesn't have phrasal verbs, what is *warten auf*?